# How do I put a code in a safe part of Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to remotely control a script written with Laravel, for example, whenever I want to close it and the site does not work.
To do this, I need to put a code in the Laravel core or where the user can easily find it.

Now, my question is, how do I put this code and what part of Laravel I can not easily find. It's safe

Answer (score 0):

If you mean shutting the server down, it depends if you are running your application with the built in server (the one you start with "php artisan serve"), or on a production server with apache/nginx. If you are running the application with the built in server, you can create a route that executes a command like "php artisan down". Obviously that isn't very safe, especially when there is no authentication/authorisation. If you are running the application on a production server you will need rights to stop the apache/nginx service and work from there I think.